# How to store and display with HTML m:n array(two dimensional table)

Tags: html, data-structures, orm, relationship, denormalization

How to organize information(in MVC model) in order to represent this real example:

**Survey** - can have multiple questions and multiple people who will answer them

**Question** - only single answer - yes or no

**PersonAnswer** - the one that answer the question

Sample display:

[image: N to M informational array]

My implementation so far is:

**DB**

Survey - Question - one to many

Question - PersonAnswer - one to many

**controller code:** - pseudo code

1. Survey.FindAllQuestions
2. Loop per each Question and find all answers
3. result is map - Survey = [Question1: AnswerList1, Question2: AnswerList2]
4. In the HTML looping over the map I'm able to diplay the information

Problems of my approach:

1. the header - people names should be calculated
2. sort of the lists is needed otherwise the answers will be mixed
3. How to manage properly if the person didn't answer a question - should I store it in the database?

**Update**: I'm using java and mysql.

Answer (score 1):

My approach to this question would first deal with the database:

In my case this is how i would do it:

```
Have a table of 

  users->represents db users
  surveyitems->with item(questions) and id(probaby autoincrement integer pkey),

 surveycheks->representing the users and their checks having({
    id(pkey),
    checkid(foreign_key ->to surveyitems table id)
    yeschecked(representing the yes)
    nochecked(representi)ng the nos
  })
```

Then in your views eg when using yii php framework

```
use gii tool to generate models and crud //here you can use your own
  logic of saving data to db

  On your survey form
   1. load all surveys from table surveyitems with id and items()// display  item
   2. Have radio buttons with values of id(from survey items);

   3.. when saving loop through all checked yes or nos and store them in surveycheks
```

I hope you get the idea